# Question about the term "hand down"?

Tags: word-meaning, legalese

What does the word "hand down" here really mean?

> travel ban was part of the verdict **handed down** on Sollecito.

Answer (score 2):

A verdict is normally a decision by a court of law.

Idiomatically, a verdict is not just delivered, it is "handed down" (I guess from the (high) bench behind which the judges would be seated).

> the verdict handed down on Sollecito

Is the legalise (legal language) for

> the decision (verdict) that a court made and announced (handed down) regarding (on) Sollecito

Comment: +1 for _idiomatically_. I imagine the phrase originated from a time when a judge would literally hand down (that is, reach down with his hand) the verdict on paper. Now, the two-word phrase could be roughly equated with "announce".